# getStaticProps not really working on Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

EDIT: I think my mistake was calling my own API like that instead of querying the MongoDB database in getStaticProps(). I refactored it this way:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
await dbConnect();

const user = await User.findOne({ email: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME })
const projects = await Project.find({})

const { description, socials, title, skills } = user;
const sortedData = skills.sort((a, b) => (a.level < b.level ? 1 : -1));

if (!user || !projects) {
    return {
        notFound: true,
    };
}
return {
    props: {
        sortedData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sortedData)),
        description,
        socials: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(socials)),
        title: title ?? '',
        projects: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projects)),
    },
    revalidate: 60,
};
```

}

and it seems to be working. I am not sure tho if that's how it's supposed to be, or it's not a good idea to go about it this way

I have this project, and when I upload it to Vercel, I get `Error: Request failed with status code 429.` I just have three API calls made in getStaticProps. I don't really know what's going on since I am new to this. I saw there's a limit but it's 3 API calls? Is there anything I am missing? Also, even when there's no error, the static page doesn't refresh at all. Actually, even when I deploy it again it doesn't change which I don't understand. On my PC with the external API and the external mongoDB everything works fine.

The API link is not that one. Just using this one in development

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/get-skills');
    const res1 = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user-info');
    const res2 = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/get-projects');
    const {
        data: { data },
    } = res;
    const {
        data: { description, socials, title },
    } = res1;
    const {
        data: { projects },
    } = res2;

    const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => (a.level < b.level ? 1 : -1));

    if (!data || !res1 || !res2) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        };
    }
    return {
        props: {
            sortedData: sortedData ?? [],
            description: description ?? '',
            socials: socials ?? [],
            title: title ?? '',
            projects: projects ?? [],
        },
        revalidate: 60,
    };
}
```

Comment: Is this a dynamic page? Are multiple pages being generated from it?

Comment: It's just the index page with multiple components. I think I figured out recoil won't work at build time so that's why I wasn't getting data. Still the 429 problem though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a rate-limit issue. Instead of using axios in getStaticProps, use `swr` inside `useEffect`

```
 import useSWR from "swr"
```

create a fetcher function:

```
const [firstState,setFirstState]=useState("")

const URL1='http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/get-skills'
const fetcher = async url => {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const json = await res.json()
  setFirstState(json)
  return json ?? []
}


useEffect(()=>{
   fetcher(URL1)
 })
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you suggested, but I think I am not allowed to use hooks in getStaticProps?